# How to dispatch the received values?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, reduce, dispatch

i have:

```
const initialState = {
    take:10,
    page: 1,
    startDate: new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate() - 3100)),
    endDate: new Date(),
    IdentityTitle: "",
    OrderStatusId: null,
  };
const reducer = (filter, action) => {
    return {
      take: action.take,
      page: action.page,
      startDate: action.startDate,
      endDate: action.endDate,
      IdentityTitle: action.IdentityTitle
    OrderStatusId: action.OrderStatusId,
     
    };
  };
  const [filter, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);
```

and when submit form in `console` I have:

```
  <TableFilter
          fields={tableFilterFields}
          onSubmit={(filters) =>
            console.log(filters)}

             /////result console:

0: {property: "StartDate", value: Tue Jun 22 2021 16:22:00 GMT+0430 (Iran Daylight Time)}
1: {property: "EndDate", value: Wed Jun 23 2021 16:22:00 GMT+0430 (Iran Daylight Time)}
2: {property: "OrderStatusId", value: 4}
3: {property: "IdentityTitle", value: "test"}

/>
```

how to dispatch in `onSubmit` mehod ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your reducer should look like this

```
const reducer = (state, action) => {
   switch(action.type){
    case "PAGE_CHANGE":
    case "NEW_ORDER":
    return {
      ...state
      take: action.payload.take,
      page: action.payload.page,
      startDate: action.payload.startDate,
      endDate: action.payload.endDate,
      IdentityTitle: action.payload.IdentityTitle
    OrderStatusId: action.payload.OrderStatusId,
     
    };
    default:
        return state;
   }
  };
```

In you onSubmit function

```
let payload = Object.fromEntries(filters.map(f => [f.property,p.value]));
dispatch({ type:"NEW_ORDER", payload:dispatchObj });
```

ON page change

```
 const pageChangeHandler = (page) => { 
   dispatch({ type:"PAGE_CHANGE", payload:{ page }}); 
 }

onPageChange={pageChangeHandler}
```

Comment: when i want page change i use this `onPageChange={pageChangeHandler}` and ` const pageChangeHandler = (page) => {
    dispatch({ ...filter, page });
  }`

Comment: Is there no way to dispatch like this?

Comment: Ok, I got your point, yup you can send like that

Comment: Can you advise me on how to do this?